# Python tkinter time delay before placing/ removing images

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, user-interface, tkinter

I have created a python tkinter program, where I want to display a series of images on a window, where the image changes every 6 seconds. When I use the code below, the whole program freezes for the entire 6 seconds.

```
loopey = "Fal"
   
while loopey == "Fal":
    time.sleep(6)
    menupic.place_forget()
    menupic2.place(x=602,y=180)
    home.update()
    time.sleep(6)
    menupic2.place_forget()
    menupic.place(x=602,y=180)
    home.update()
```

I also tried to use the after() function, but had the same issue.

```
def deletion(thing):
    thing.place_forget()


while True:
    home.after(6000, deletion(menupic))
    menupic2.place(x=602,y=180)
    home.update()
    home.after(6000, deletion(menupic2))
    menupic.place(x=602,y=180)
    home.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from random import randint
import numpy as np


def place_image():
    npimg = np.zeros([100,100,3],dtype=np.uint8)
    npimg.fill(randint(0, 255))
    pilimg = Image.fromarray(npimg)
    tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilimg)
    label.img = tkimg
    label.configure(image=tkimg)
    home.after(6000, place_image)

home = Tk()

label = Label(home, text="test")
label.place(x=0, y=0)

home.after(6000, place_image)
home.mainloop()
```

If you use after() also in the function you can still interact with the window.
It wil still loop trought every 6 seconds.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I added another copy of your loop and had the 2 loops call each other to place the images on the screen. Have a great day.